# remove b', \r, \n' in 1 enormous line

Tags: python, file, url

```
url = FINAM_URL + symbol+"_" + start_date_rev + "_" + end_date_rev + ".csv?" + params
txt=str(urlopen(url).readlines())
local_file = open('company_quotes.txt', "w")
local_file.write(txt)
local_file.close()
```

I get a file with 1 very large string
[image]

I wish my file to be without b', \r, \n' symbols and look like this (many lines):

[image]

Comment: txt.replace("b'", "") ?

Answer (score 2):

The `b` indicates a bytes object, You have to convert bytes to string using `.decode( "utf-8" )`. You also have to use `.strip()` in order to remove extra characters like `\n\r` at the ends of strings.

So use:

```
for line in lines:
    clean_line = line.strip().decode( "utf-8" )
```

Comment: I understood your answer.... but it doesn't work... Error http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2018/10/12/0011/1313/742689/89/213fb76fb1.png

Comment: The lines are not byte objects, they are written in the syntax of a byte object. Therefore you cannot decode them

Answer (score 1):

The data you are getting from that URL are bytes, as such you can just write the data directly to your file in binary format as follows:

```
url = FINAM_URL + symbol+"_" + start_date_rev + "_" + end_date_rev + ".csv?" + params
data = urlopen(url).read()

with open('company_quotes.txt', 'wb') as local_file:
    local_file.write(data)
```

The `\r\n` symbols are newline characters, so writing them as shown would result in your file being correctly written as multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

Using replace()

```
with open('company_quotes.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines:
        line = line.replace('\r\n', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

`txt=str(urlopen(url).readlines())` is the issue.  You need to call `.decode()` on each line instead of using `str()`.  For example:

```
with open('company_quotes.txt', "w") as local_file:
    for line in urlopen(url).readlines():
        local_file.write(line.decode())
```